# Should question owners be able to down vote on answers?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, down-votes, privileges, up-votes

I have had a few questions with not so good answers. Could it be possible that question askers can down vote (or up vote) on answers to their questions, without rep requirements?

Also, about up voting, if an answer is partially helpful or useful, we should be able to express that it worked.

Is it possible that this could be considered?

Comment: You only need 15 rep to vote up an answer  which is not that high, and unless I'm missing something the right way to say "this worked" is to accept the answer. You are able to leave comments on all answers to your own question as well so until you get the required rep you can tell them more directly whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Voting down has the meaning that the post is of a very low quality; but it's still frequently used with a meaning of "I don't agree with it", "it doesn't work for me". This is nor different for the answers of your own question (an answer not solving your problem can still be very helpful for others with similar problem).

Until reaching 125 rep for the ability of down-voting most users hopefully learn this.

And as very well commented for your question: Commenting has much more power for improving answers then down-voting them.

Comment: But they don't learn.  Down votes are still mainly used for "I don't like this" and "I don't know anything about it".

Comment: @RohitGupta - It also is used for "this answer has numerous technical problems, is incomplete, is a comment, is a new problem itself, is asking far to many questions to the author" all of which are valid reasons for the vote.